# piping sed | awk or awk | sed

Tags: linux, awk, sed, pipe

I can definitely be considered a sed/awk newbie.  I have been working to do a multi-step filter without success.  Each segment yields results when run on it's own, but when I chain them together I get nothing.  I've tried sed|awk, awk|sed, sed|sed, awk|awk.  They all fail so I'm assuming it's something well known by everyone but me.

The data is multi-line blocks of text, where each block can be treated as a record (hence the ">" delimiter).  After we filter to just the ADV_NONCONN blocks, I'd like to then filter down the block of text to only the lines containing "bdaddr" or "RSSI".  As far as I know, I'd need to pipe into a separate operation to do so.

```
sudo hcidump | awk 'BEGIN {RS=">"} /ADV_NONCONN/' | sed -n -e "/bdaddr/p" -e "/RSSI/p" > log.txt
```

hcidump output sample (one "record"):

```
HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 43
    LE Advertising Report
      ADV_NONCONN_IND - Non connectable undirected advertising (3)
      bdaddr 0C:F3:EE:0D:70:89 (Public)
      Flags: 0x06
      Unknown type 0xff with 26 bytes data
      RSSI: -62
```

Running the inverse (the sed portion first, then awk) gives same empty set results.  What simple thing have I missed?

Comment: It's almost never necessary to pipe `awk` to `sed`, since `awk` can do most things that `sed` can do, and the `awk` syntax is usually easier to understand.

Comment: Allow me to give you some feedback: both your question and your own answer are chatty to the point of distraction - please consider making them more concise and focused.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, so I eventually figured it out.  I believe that the awk output is not eminently pipe-able because of some sort of buffering/not closing that it is doing with the input stream.  Since the original question, I've added the timestamp from the hcidump.

So, first I prepend a unique character (@) before the timestamp with sed, then pipe that to awk, which treats the multiple lines as a single record using that unique character (@) as the record delimiter, filters to the records I want (ADV_NONCONN) then assembles the appropriate output from the fields it reads (which now includes the timestamp at the head of the record).

```
sudo hcidump -t | sed -n '/HCI Event/{s/^/@/};p' | awk 'BEGIN {RS="@"} {-F '[\n]'} /ADV_NONCONN/ {print $1 " " $2 ", " $23 ", " $35}' > a.txt
```

The solution to the original question would be:

```
sudo hcidump | awk 'BEGIN {RS=">"} {-F '[\n]'} /ADV_NONCONN/ {print $20 ", " $32}' > a.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to pipe `awk` to `sed`. Just add additional conditions in the `awk` command:

```
sudo hcidump | awk -v RS=">" '/ADV_NONCONN/ {
    n = split($0, line, /\n/);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (line[i] ~ /bdaddr|RSSI/) print line[i];
    }
}' > log.txt
```

Comment: I think I missed a bit of detail (I'll add to original question).  Each record awk processes is a multi-line block of text.  After awk filters to records containing ADV_NONCONN, I need to filter to only the lines in that record block that contain either bdaddr or RSSI.  Your awk snippet gives me empty set as well.

Comment: I've revised it to loop over the lines in the block in `awk`.

Comment: But I admit that now this is not as simple as your original attempt, and I'm not sure why it didn't work.

Comment: That's got it.  Thanks.  I'm still not sure why I couldn't pipe the output of awk and then process it with sed, but at least for this instance it doesn't matter.  Cheers.

Comment: You don't need to use `split()` to create an array, just set `-F'\n'` and loop on the fields.